# How to make vercel import DNS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dns, vercel

I am making a project and I try put it in the vercel, but have this errors:

```
[12:34:28.806] Cloning github.com/Samuel-Schlemper-Schlemuel/Save_URL (Branch: main, Commit: f60a16f)
[12:34:29.040] Cloning completed: 234.251ms
[12:34:29.433] Looking up build cache...
[12:34:30.291] Build cache downloaded [4.39 MB]: 497.872ms
[12:34:30.323] Running "vercel build"
[12:34:30.805] Vercel CLI 28.4.7
[12:34:30.933] WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
[12:34:31.424] Installing dependencies...
[12:34:31.775] yarn install v1.22.17
[12:34:31.795] info No lockfile found.
[12:34:31.799] [1/5] Validating package.json...
[12:34:31.802] [2/5] Resolving packages...
[12:34:32.145] warning dns > winston > request@2.16.6: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[12:34:32.193] warning dns > winston > request > hawk@0.10.2: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
[12:34:32.199] warning dns > winston > request > node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
[12:34:32.296] warning dns > winston > request > hawk > hoek@0.7.6: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
[12:34:32.299] warning dns > winston > request > aws-sign@0.2.1: Incorrectly published ES6 version into the 0.x branch
[12:34:32.301] warning dns > winston > request > hawk > boom@0.3.8: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
[12:34:32.302] warning dns > winston > request > hawk > boom > hoek@0.7.6: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
[12:34:32.321] warning dns > winston > request > hawk > cryptiles@0.1.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
[12:34:32.322] warning dns > winston > request > hawk > cryptiles > boom@0.3.8: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
[12:34:32.334] warning dns > winston > request > hawk > sntp@0.1.4: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
[12:34:32.335] warning dns > winston > request > hawk > sntp > hoek@0.7.6: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
[12:34:32.662] warning dns > tomahawk > socket.io > socket.io-parser > json3@3.2.6: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3
[12:34:32.662] warning dns > tomahawk > socket.io > socket.io-adapter > socket.io-parser > json3@3.2.6: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3
[12:34:32.790] error An unexpected error occurred: "http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vercel/.cache/yarn/v6/.tmp/c093b6de586a0ae2ebbab27ba3b833a5/.yarn-tarball.tgz'".
[12:34:32.791] info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/vercel/path0/yarn-error.log".
[12:34:32.791] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
[12:34:35.327] Build Completed in /vercel/output [4s]
[12:34:38.156] Generated build outputs:
[12:34:38.157]  - Static files: 0
[12:34:38.157]  - Serverless Functions: 1
[12:34:38.157]  - Edge Functions: 0
[12:34:38.157] Serverless regions: Washington, D.C., USA
[12:34:38.157] Deployed outputs in 2s
[12:34:38.994] Build completed. Populating build cache...
[12:34:41.297] Uploading build cache [4.39 MB]...
[12:34:42.143] Build cache uploaded: 845.755ms
[12:34:42.168] Done with "."
```

I am loking for put this project in the vercel, I imagine that error is because the vercel don't import de DNS librery, and I am loking for a mean to make the vercel function with the DNS, this is my package.json and my vercel.json, respectively:

```
{
    "name": "url_saver",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A FCC project",
    "main": "index.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": "14.x"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "dns": "^0.2.2",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "mongoose": "^6.6.2",
        "url": "^0.11.0"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "node",
        "express",
        "freecodecamp",
        "mongoose"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": "Samuel Schlemper"
}
```

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Project link: https://github.com/Samuel-Schlemper-Schlemuel/Save_URL

I prefer to use vercel UI or change some of my files if possible, but if necessary I can use command line too

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a library called dns-lookup which only has the dns.lookup() function and I used it to fix my project and make it work, although I haven't figured out how to import the DNS library itself.